# Pandas replace DataFrame values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace the values of a column in a df based on the corresponding index value pair in another df.

For example:

main df:

```
d = {'var1': [A, B, A, B]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    var1   
0     A     
1     B     
2     A     
3     B
```

Data frame with new values:

```
df2  val1

A     1     
B     2
```

Result:

```
df
    var1   
0     1    
1     2    
2     1   
3     2
```

I was thinking I could set var1 as a temporary index then join with df2 and then replace the var1 column with val1. Not sure if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Use `map` : `df['var1'].map(df2['val1'])`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`df.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df.var1=df.var1.map(df_new.set_index('df2')['val1'])
print(df)

   var1
0     1
1     2
2     1
3     2
```

Comment: Maybe try something new `df2.val1.get(df.var1)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thank you. :) I will study more on `get()` thanks for teaching me that. :)