# Replace specific value in pandas dataframe column, else convert column to numeric

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

Given the following pandas dataframe

```
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    |   AgeAt_X        |   AgeAt_Y                           |   AgeAt_Z                      |
|----+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|  0 |   Older than 100 |                      Older than 100 |                          74.13 |
|  1 |              nan |                                 nan |                          58.46 |
|  2 |              nan |                                 8.4 |                          54.15 |
|  3 |              nan |                                 nan |                          57.04 |
|  4 |              nan |                               57.04 |                            nan |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

how can I replace values in specific columns which equal `Older than 100` with `nan`

```
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|    |   AgeAt_X        |   AgeAt_Y                           |   AgeAt_Z                      |
|----+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|  0 |              nan |                                 nan |                          74.13 |
|  1 |              nan |                                 nan |                          58.46 |
|  2 |              nan |                                 8.4 |                          54.15 |
|  3 |              nan |                                 nan |                          57.04 |
|  4 |              nan |                               57.04 |                            nan |
+----+------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

**Notes**

- After removing the `Older than 100` string from the desired columns, I convert the columns to numeric in order to perform calculations on said columns.
- There are other columns in this dataframe (that I have excluded from this example), which will not be converted to numeric, so the conversion to numeric must be done one column at a time.

**What I've tried**

**Attempt 1**

```
if df.isin('Older than 100'):
    df.loc[df['AgeAt_X']] = ''
else:
    df['AgeAt_X'] = pd.to_numeric(df["AgeAt_X"])
```

**Attempt 2**

```
if df.loc[df['AgeAt_X']] == 'Older than 100r':
    df.loc[df['AgeAt_X']] = ''
elif df.loc[df['AgeAt_X']] == '':
    df['AgeAt_X'] = pd.to_numeric(df["AgeAt_X"])
```

**Attempt 3**

```
df['AgeAt_X'] = ['' if ele == 'Older than 100' else df.loc[df['AgeAt_X']] for ele in df['AgeAt_X']]
```

Attempts 1, 2 and 3 return the following error:

`KeyError: 'None of [0      NaN\n1      NaN\n2      NaN\n3      NaN\n4      NaN\n5      NaN\n6      NaN\n7      NaN\n8      NaN\n9      NaN\n10     NaN\n11     NaN\n12     NaN\n13     NaN\n14     NaN\n15     NaN\n16     NaN\n17     NaN\n18     NaN\n19     NaN\n20     NaN\n21     NaN\n22     NaN\n23     NaN\n24     NaN\n25     NaN\n26     NaN\n27     NaN\n28     NaN\n29     NaN\n        ..\n6332   NaN\n6333   NaN\n6334   NaN\n6335   NaN\n6336   NaN\n6337   NaN\n6338   NaN\n6339   NaN\n6340   NaN\n6341   NaN\n6342   NaN\n6343   NaN\n6344   NaN\n6345   NaN\n6346   NaN\n6347   NaN\n6348   NaN\n6349   NaN\n6350   NaN\n6351   NaN\n6352   NaN\n6353   NaN\n6354   NaN\n6355   NaN\n6356   NaN\n6357   NaN\n6358   NaN\n6359   NaN\n6360   NaN\n6361   NaN\nName: AgeAt_X, Length: 6362, dtype: float64] are in the [index]'`

**Attempt 4**

```
df['AgeAt_X'] = df['AgeAt_X'].replace({'Older than 100': ''})
```

Attempt 4 returns the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=float64)' and 'str'`

I've also looked at a few posts. The two below do not actually replace the value but create a new column derived from others

[Replace specific values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557895/replace-specific-values-in-pandas-dataframe/49558169#49558169)

[Pandas replace DataFrame values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342023/pandas-replace-dataframe-values)

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd want to keep *other non-numeric* values in the columns? If there isn't and it just turns out that `'Older than 100'` is the only problematic string, then the way to go is `pd.to_numeric(df['col_name'], errors='coerce')`

Comment: @ALollz, good idea. I'll try this and report back tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @ALollz, I believe your solution is the best by far. From the docs `If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html). This is exactly want I need and only requires setting a parameter and no additional code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through each column and check if the sentence is present. If we get a hit, we replace the sentence with `NaN` with [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and right after convert it to numeric with [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), in this case `float`:

```
df.dtypes
AgeAt_X     object
AgeAt_Y     object
AgeAt_Z    float64
dtype: object

sent = 'Older than 100'

for col in df.columns:
    if sent in df[col].values:
        df[col] = df[col].str.replace(sent, 'NaN')
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)

print(df)
   AgeAt_X  AgeAt_Y  AgeAt_Z
0      NaN      NaN    74.13
1      NaN      NaN    58.46
2      NaN     8.40    54.15
3      NaN      NaN    57.04
4      NaN    57.04      NaN

df.dtypes
AgeAt_X    float64
AgeAt_Y    float64
AgeAt_Z    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks @Erfan, this solution saved me the step of identifying the columns to convert to numeric individually.

Comment: Nice solution, but the for loop and `.astype(float)` lines are unnecessary, because if the replacement results in a column with all numeric values, pandas automatically casts that column to numeric data type. A shorter solution is `df.replace('Older than 100', np.nan, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can replace all occurrences of `Older than 100` with `np.nan` with a single call to `DataFrame.replace`. If all remaining values are numeric, then **the replace will implicitly change the data type of the column to numeric**:

```
# Minimal example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'AgeAt_X': ['Older than 100', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'AgeAt_Y': ['Older than 100', np.nan, 8.4],
                   'AgeAt_Z': [74.13, 58.46, 54.15]})
df
          AgeAt_X         AgeAt_Y  AgeAt_Z
0  Older than 100  Older than 100    74.13
1             NaN             NaN    58.46
2             NaN             8.4    54.15

df.dtypes
AgeAt_X     object
AgeAt_Y     object
AgeAt_Z    float64
dtype: object

# Replace occurrences of 'Older than 100' with np.nan in any column
df.replace('Older than 100', np.nan, inplace=True)

df
   AgeAt_X  AgeAt_Y  AgeAt_Z
0      NaN      NaN    74.13
1      NaN      NaN    58.46
2      NaN      8.4    54.15

df.dtypes
AgeAt_X    float64
AgeAt_Y    float64
AgeAt_Z    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This works for his example, but this would not be sufficient while converting to numeric, since it wont check of presence `Older than 100` in each column.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Leimbigler, your solution did work but Erfan's solution did as well but also mitigated the need for me to identify the columns I wanted to convert to numeric, because if they contained `Older than 100`, I was going to convert them anyways.

Comment: In fact, there is no need for explicit conversion to numeric data types. If the string replacement results in a column with all numeric values, pandas implicitly converts the data type of that column to a numeric type, in this case `float64`. I've edited my answer to reflect this behaviour.

Comment: Though, with an object column that contains numeric-like values and strings, `pandas` will typically read in `1` as `'1'`, and in those cases it doesn't get typecast (Data like `7,8;foo,9`)

Comment: @Alollz, good point, doesn't look like that's the case with this example data, but may occur in other columns.